# Javascript Fizzbuzz Issue

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I'm trying to do some simple tests to help further my javascript knowledge (which is quite fresh). Goal 1 is to print numbers from 1-100 that aren't divisible by 5 or 3.

I tried the following:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i ++) 
{
    if (i%3 !== 0 || i%5 !== 0){
        console.log(i);
    }

}
```

This logs EVERY number from 1-100, and I can't tell why. Probably the simplest simplest questions here but it's doing my head in!

Comment: It's actually not logging every number - it skips every multiple of 15!

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for not giving it totally away, as I'm really trying to learn here. I thought || means "or", so if i%3 is 0 (which means it's divisible by 3) shouldn't it be printing those numbers?

Comment: You're forgetting about the other case: `i % 5 !== 0`

Comment: I think I've got it now. But in the code above, if `i===3`, shouldn't that make `i%3!==0` false, which means `i%5!==0` shouldn't even evaluate?

Comment: You're using `||`, the logic `or` operator; the entire condition evaluates to true if either the left condition or the right condition is true. Incidentally, `i%3 !== 0 || i%5 !== 0` means the exact same thing as `i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0`, by De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean `&&`, not `||`. With `||`, you're basically testing to see if the number is not divisible by 3 or by 5 - only if a number is divisible by both do you reject it (in other words, multiples of 15).

The typical answer to FizzBuzz is:

```
if( i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0) FizzBuzz
elseif( i % 3 == 0) Fizz
elseif( i % 5 == 0) Buzz
else number
```

So to get directly to the number you need for `i%3==0` to be false AND `i%5==0` to be false. Therefore, you want `if( i%3 !== 0 && i%5 !== 0)`

Comment: It's not actual code, I just put them there to essentially say "put Fizz-writing code here"

Comment: Whoops, deleted my comment. Yeah I figured that as soon as I posted it! Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: No problem :) In future if you have problems like this, try getting some paper and drawing out a Truth Table. Run some values through it and see if it seems right. That would help you find problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quite simple FizzBuzz function that accepts a range of numbers.

```js
function fizzBuzz(from, to) {
  for(let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    let msg = ''
    if(i % 3 == 0) msg += 'Fizz'
    if(i % 5 == 0) msg += 'Buzz'

    if(msg.length == 0) msg = i

    console.log(msg)
  }
}

fizzBuzz(1, 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

As for a more complex solution, that's one way you could define a higher order function which generates customized FizzBuzz functions (with additional divisors and keywords)

```js
function fizzBuzzFactory(keywords) {
  return (from, to) => {
    for(let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
      let msg = ''
      Reflect.ownKeys(keywords).forEach((keyword) => {
        let divisor = keywords[keyword]
        if(i % divisor == 0) msg += keyword
      })

      if(msg.length == 0) msg = i

      console.log(msg)
    }
  }
}

// generates a new function
const classicFizzBuzz = fizzBuzzFactory({ Fizz: 3, Buzz: 5 })
// accepts a range of numbers
classicFizzBuzz(1, 25)

const extendedFizzBuzz = fizzBuzzFactory({ Fizz: 3, Buzz: 5, Bazz: 7, Fuzz: 11 })
extendedFizzBuzz(1, 25)
```

Answer (score -1):

I attacked this the same was as Niet the Dark Absol:

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
    if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0)
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    else if (n % 3 == 0)
        console.log("Fizz");
    else if (n % 5 == 0)
        console.log("Buzz");
    else
            console.log(n);
}
```

However, you can also do it this way:

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
    var output = "";
    if (n % 3 == 0)
        output += "Fizz";
    if (n % 5 == 0)
        output += "Buzz";
    console.log(output || n);
}
```

One of the hardest parts of learning JavaScript - or any language - for me is understanding solutions can come in many ways. I like the first example more, but it's always good to keep thinking and look at other options.